# Getting around FetchXML's outer join limitation

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-online

Is there a way to get a list of all opportunities by territory(territory is defined in account) closing in next 30-60-90 days using FetchXML in the online
version of Dynamics CRM 2011.

I tried to do this by writing SQL on a test database and it is possible by using the following SQL:

```sql
select Territory.TerritoryId ,
 (select count(OpportunityId) from Opportunity where Opportunity.AccountId = Account.AccountId and Account.TerritoryId = Territory.TerritoryId and EstimatedClosureDate < '12/12/2011') as OppIn30Days,
 (select count(OpportunityId) from Opportunity where Opportunity.AccountId = Account.AccountId and Account.TerritoryId = Territory.TerritoryId and EstimatedClosureDate < '12/1/2012') as OppIn60Days,
 (select count(OpportunityId) from Opportunity where Opportunity.AccountId = Account.AccountId and Account.TerritoryId = Territory.TerritoryId and EstimatedClosureDate < '12/2/2012') as OppIn90Days
  from territory left outer join Account on Territory.TerritoryId = Account.TerritoryId --group by Territory.TerritoryId, Account.TerritoryId, Account.AccountId
-- TODO parameterization of query, etc.
```

the result for the SQL looks like this.

```
Columns: TerritoryId|OpportunitiesClosingIn30Days|OpportunitiesClosingIn60Days
Data:   US              5                                   1
        Europe          1                                   4
        Asia            4                                   5
```

Is this possible to do this using FetchXML since outer joins are not supported?

Would it help if I added a hidden territory field in Opportunity and wrote some code so that everytime an opportunity is created the territory is copied from the corresponding account?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this isn't possible with FetchXML. You *may* be able to dummy it up using a report that pulls in all the relevant data then manipulates it for display, but you'd need an SSRS guru to answer that for you.

Your suggestion of denormalised data is probably on the right path: If you add `Territory` to your opportunity, you can then use the MSCRM Dashboards to show opportunities closing by month by territory.